# Удалить метку "пунктуации"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки

Предлагаю объединить метки "пунктуация" и "пунктуации" или удалить "пунктуации", если возможно. По-моему, слово *пунктуация* не должно употребляться во множественном числе.

Answer (score 1):

Метки объединены, синоним создан. Спасибо за помощь!